# Slackware cannot reconnect to local network

Tags: networking, slackware, ifconfig

Hi guys this problem is frustrating me.

After trying a lot of things to setup my wireless card, I decide to test it by shutting down LAN interface `ifconfig eth0 down`. Then, when I turn the LAN interface back on (`ifconfig eth0 up`), it won't let me connect again.

Anybody knows why my LAN cannot be turned back on?

Currently I "solve" the problem by restarting the whole computer, but if I ever `ifconfig eth0 down` again I would have to restart to bring it back :(

**Edit**: previously this question was a combination of 2 question, you can see the second question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/84622/setup-wireless-networking-on-slackware).

Comment: what do you ping? an IP address or a hostname? I suspect DNS here..

Comment: i'm pinging an IP address, and i can open that address on another computer...

Comment: ok, then your problem is most likely DNS. First of all: do you have any kind of network protection (WPA, wep, etc)? Does your network card join the network correctly? (try `iwconfig`). If your wireless card correctly joined the network, and you can't ping a hostname - then it's a DNS problem (check /etc/resolv.conf). If you are not on the wireless network either, then you first need to join it and configure the key correctly. Do post more information please.

Comment: my network is not encrypted and i have joined it (that's why i can ping IP addresses)
it's true that i cannot ping hostnames, but if it's a DNS problem i should still be able to access the page using its IP address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this would solve the problem:

```
/etc/rc.d/inet1 eth0_restart
```

But personally I think `ifconfig eth0 up` should be enough, maybe slackware is being weird...

Comment: Simply setting the interface to up does not set its IP address and netmask, nor does it start the DHCP client software.

Comment: yeah you are right, maybe I have been spoiled by ubuntu, which does that automatically when I `ifconfig eth0 up`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read this (or the whole page, which is very well written): http://alien.slackbook.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=slackware:network#re_starting_a_network_interface

You can run ifconfig ... up or down to activate/deactivate an interface. But this doesn't **configure** the interface which is necessary to connect. As stated in the slackbook page you linked to, the rc scripts need to be run. This is to set the IP addresses according to the configuration files (e.g. dynamic or static address configuration), connect to wireless networks (in case it is a wireless interface), etc.

Comment: thanks for the link, but I have already run those scripts so many time now