# setup wireless networking on slackware

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, slackware, connection

I am trying to set up wifi on slackware, following [this guide](http://www.slackbook.org/html/network-configuration-wireless.html). Everything is good, and as you can see below I am able to join the network (`Link Quality=75/100`). However I cannot access anything, and `ping` just does not work. I tried to `ping` pages by IP address as well, but it failed so this is not a problem with DNS. Also, it appears that I cannot acquire an IP address
This is the result of `iwconfig`

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"rmitvnnet"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:19:E1:0D:FB:04   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=27 dBm   
          Retry min limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr=2352 B   
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=75/100  Signal level:-83 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

This is the result of `ifconfig wlan0`

```
wlan0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:43:61:a2:f0
        inet6 addr: fe80::222:43ff:fe61:a2f0/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:4526 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:779355 (761.0 KiB)  TX bytes:498 (498.0 B)
```

This is the result of `ip addr show wlan0`

```
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:43:61:a2:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::222:43ff:fe61:a2f0/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And this is my configuration in rc.wireless.conf

```
VERBOSE=1
case "$HWADDR" in
00:22:43:*)
    INFO="Multiband Atheros based 802.11a/b/g universal NIC"
    ESSID="rmitvnnet"
    MODE="Managed"
    CHANNEL="1"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: well I'm starting a bounty now... this is on my wish list

Comment: Please add the output of "ip addr show wlan0" or "ifconfig wlan0" so we know the layer 2 configuration.

Comment: do other computers work on the wireless setup?

Comment: @John T: yes the network is in use and other computers are working fine (most of them are using windows, a few using ubuntu which doesn't need to config anything)
@camh: I'm going to upload that

Comment: Can you post your rc.wireless.conf?

Comment: there you go, I also removed the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wondering if you have tried running the **dhcp** client on *wlan0* to see if it obtains an IP address automatically.

Comment: yeah cool thankyou this is just what I need

Comment: can't remember how to do it, but you can automate dhcp in the slackware init scripts too, probably one of the networking configurations, so that it does it whenever it starts up wireless networking.

Comment: `dhcpcd wlan0` just does its job, I'll go look further into automatic scripts

Comment: yeah and for the automatic dhcp, you need `USE_DHCP[n]="yes"` in `/etc/rc.d/rc.inet1`, where `n` is the index of your interface

Answer (score 1):

You have no encryption key in your rc.wireless.conf, is there no encryption in place? If there is you'll need to add it. Also, try connecting without specifying a channel:

```
VERBOSE=1
case "$HWADDR" in
00:22:43:*)
    INFO="Multiband Atheros based 802.11a/b/g universal NIC"
    ESSID="rmitvnnet"
    KEY="s:password_here"
    MODE="Managed"
    ;;
esac
```

Change `password_here` with your wireless key. If it still doesn't work, try setting the channel (if you know it).

You may also be interested in [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/). It is way easier than messing with `rc.wireless.conf`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot John, but I don't have any key. BTW the other guy got the answer